# tuple index out of range in tensorflow Concatenate

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tuples, concatenation

This is my first time using concatenate,
I am building a NN for a deep learning project,
one class defines the concatenate, and that class runs fine.

The next def includes concatenate, and it is giving me a ' tuple index out of range"
I am fairly confused of where to fix this..
I m uploading parts of my code, please help.

```
def call(self, x):
    self.conc = concatenate([])
    x = self.flatten(x)
    r = x # residual / short-cut / skip connection
    if self.probe_num == -1: # for network training
      for (i, layer) in enumerate(self.my_layers):
        if i == SkipLayer_2:
          x = self.conc([x, r])
          x = layer(x)
          return x
    else: # for probe training
      for (i, layer) in enumerate(self.my_layers[0:self.probe_num]):
        if i == SkipLayer_2:
          x = self.conc([x, r])
          x = layer(x)
          x = tf.stop_gradient(x)
          probe = self.probes[self.probe_num]
    return probe(x)
```

and

```
for probe_num in range(len(model.my_probe)):
  model.probe_num = probe_num
  model(X_train[0:Batch_2])
weights = model.get_weights()

probe_error = probe_training(weights)
```

give me

```
   IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-bfb6ffd6d257> in <module>()
     51 for probe_num in range(len(model.my_probe)):
     52   model.probe_num = probe_num
---> 53   model(X_train[0:Batch_2])
     54 weights = model.get_weights()
     55 


<ipython-input-21-6f2bfe4c9db1> in call(self, x)
     21     # Call
     22   def call(self, x):
---> 23     self.conc = concatenate([])
     24     x = self.flatten(x)
     25     r = x # residual / short-cut / skip connection

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/merge.py in concatenate(inputs, axis, **kwargs)
    929       A tensor, the concatenation of the inputs alongside axis `axis`.
    930   """
--> 931   return Concatenate(axis=axis, **kwargs)(inputs)


7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/merge.py in build(self, input_shape)
    490   def build(self, input_shape):
    491     # Used purely for shape validation.
--> 492     if not isinstance(input_shape[0], tuple) or len(input_shape) < 2:
    493       raise ValueError('A `Concatenate` layer should be called '
    494                        'on a list of at least 2 inputs')

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.conc = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()
```

And put tis line into **init**() rather than into call().